# Wrap a div around every 4 items in a loop

Tags: php

I need to add `<div class="row">` around the number of items set in `$woocommerce_loop['columns']`.  I need output to look like:

```
<div class="row">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</div>
```

What I currently have is only wrapping the div around every 4th list item.

```
<?php
    // Store loop count we're currently on
    if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] ) )
        $woocommerce_loop['loop'] = 0;

    // Store column count for displaying the grid
    if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) )
        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', 4 );

    // Ensure visibility
    if ( ! $product->is_visible() )
        return;

    // Increase loop count
    $woocommerce_loop['loop']++;

    if ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] == 0) {
        echo '<div class="row">';
    }
?>

<li>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
    <a style="position: relative;display: block;" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>
        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>
    </a>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    </a>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
</li>
<?php 
    if ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] == 0) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

This is a template being called inside a loop in case you're wondering where the loop is.

Comment: Ummm... why aren't you using a table for what appears to be tabular data?

Comment: More importantly, you shouldn't put `<li>`s inside of `<div>`s. That is invalid HTML.

Comment: Not sure how it appears to be tabular data but its not.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok how about wrap it with a `<ul>`.  This isnt HTML class.  This is the PHP section.

Comment: Theres a lot of mention of rows and columsn and its being pulled from a database. Seems pretty tabular. Can you give us an example of what you are expecting to see (rather than just dummy data)?

Comment: It appears that you already know everything, and peoples queries for more information or help aren't really needed. Why do you want our help again?

Comment: A `<ul>` would be perfect; and yes I'm aware of the fact that your question is PHP focused, I just felt it would be beneficial for you if I pointed that out.

Comment: Try changing the 1st `if ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] == 0)` to `if ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] == 1)`. Leave the 2nd as `if ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] == 0)`. That way it opens on the 1st, and closes on the 4th.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I apologize if that came off brash.

Comment: Thanks Sean.  Thats it.  Provide an answer and I will choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
if ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] == 1) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
}

...

if ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] == 0) {
    echo '</div>';
}
```

This way it opens on the 1st, and closes on the 4th.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the simplest answer is to use a variable to keep track of number of iterations and add when mod 4 = 0...

```
$count = 0;
if($count % $numOfRows == 0 || $count == 0)
{
    if($count % $numOfRows == 0)
         echo "</div>"
    if($count != count($arrayYourLoopingThrough) -1)
        echo "<div class='row'>";
}

elseif($count == count($arrayYourLoopingThrough) -1)
    echo "</div>";
```

probably be better if you used a list instead of a div with a class but this should do what you asked for.

Comment: missing conditoon to close tag if last item isn;t divisible by 4